# Is "paparrucha" a good translation of "fake news" and "post-truth"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, etimología, neologismos

A tweet has become quite successful during the last weeks:

> Vosotros hablando de «fake news» y «posverdad» cuando el castellano tiene una palabra hermosa para eso:
>   [image]
>    <sub>([source](https://twitter.com/lacrimaererum86/status/908035194556477441))</sub>

That is:

> Y'all taking about "fake news" and "posverdad" when Spanish has a beautiful word for that: [***paparrucha***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RlvnOag).

Where *posverdad* is the Spanish translation of ["post-truth"](http://www.huffingtonpost.es/2016/11/16/palabra-ano-2016_n_13004172.html).

And indeed the author seems to be right, as DLE defines the word as:

> [**paparrucha**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RlvnOag)
>   De *páparo*.
>   1. f. coloq. Noticia falsa y desatinada de un suceso, esparcida entre el vulgo.
>   2. f. coloq. Tontería, estupidez, cosa insustancial y desatinada.
>   3. f. León. Masa blanda, como la del barro.

Where *páparo* refers to the second definition here:

> [**páparo, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RlpRY42)
>   De papa<sup>3</sup>.
>   1. adj. Dicho de una persona: De una tribu, ya extinguida, del istmo de Panamá. U. t. c. s.
>   2. m. Aldeano u hombre del campo, simple e ignorante, que de cualquier cosa que ve, para él extraordinaria, se queda admirado y pasmado.

And [**papo<sup>3</sup>**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ro4izPP) means *dumb* in Honduras.

Considering the Oxford dictionary defines [*post-truth*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/post-truth) as:

> Relating to or denoting circumstances in which objective facts are less influential in shaping public opinion than appeals to emotion and personal belief.

Can we assume both words are equivalent, so *paparrucha* is indeed the (proper) translation of *post-truth* into Spanish?

Comment: También tenemos [filfa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HuR8H75) o [bulo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6HojyGw) para noticia falsa, [patraña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SAuMlOF) es otra que podría valer

Comment: ¿Se puede decir noticias falsas en castellano?

Comment: Esa palabra nunca la había oído. Patrañas es la que usaríamos por aquí.

Comment: I ve never heard of that word at all. I would not understand it

Comment: User @Diego deleted my answer saying it "does not provide an answer to the question". Well, it did. I have never heard that word and would not understand it. That is clearly an answer.

Comment: @walen - If a moderator carries out a slightly heavy-handed action (which in this case I have flagged, as I think it would be better to at least convert a poorly developed answer to a comment, rather than wiping it off the face of the page like a bolt of lightning), and the participant objects, let's be careful that the participant doesn't start to feel dog-piled.

Comment: @KansaiRobot - This is a young site, please bear with us, we're still figuring out how to keep up our standards while not scaring off newcomers.  Meanwhile, I have a suggestion for you: if something like this happens to you again here or on another SE site, raise a flag, or post on the sister Meta site.  In this case you don't need to because I already raised a flag.

Comment: @fedorqui - The consensus seems to be that it's not "the proper translation" -- but Twitter is a very informal medium and it seems to me that if you provide some context to make sure your audience is understanding you, it might be nice to include this word to give some extra color.  When I see or hear something ending in "ucha" I get some extra meaning.  "Paparrucha" has a nice expressive tone.

Comment: @KansaiRobot - So, what has happened is that a moderator responded to my flag and instead of simply *removing* what you wrote, converted it to a comment.  I will wish you a belated Welcome to the Site.  Stick around.  Things will get easier with experience. // (Thanks, mods!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the tweet thread, you'll see that Fundéu have answered and I agree with them: unlike *fake news*, *paparrucha* is an informal term in Spanish. *Noticias falsas* is perfectly fine for me.

As for *post-truth*, as others have said, it has a different meaning. The simple direct translation *posverdad* is, once again, perfectly fine for me. The prefix *post-* (or *pos-*) has been used in Spanish before with the same meaning and intention.

Answer (score 4):

I also saw the tweet and I liked it very much :)

However, even though RAE provides a definition that makes "paparrucha" very close to "post-verdad" and "fake news", I have two objections to the usage of the former instead of the latter two. Both objections are from a subjective point of view, though:

- First, I consider it a little bit **obsolete**. Frankly, I only know it because of old comics (Zipi y Zape, el Tío Gilito), and I would consider it old-fashioned in modern Spanish discourse.
- Second, for me it has a very **pejorative** nuance, while "post-verdad" and "fake news" are kind of more neutral. I mean. I would only use "paparruchas" if I'm trying to discredit someone's discourse, and I would find it to be out of context, for instance, in the written press or in TV news.

P.S. All of this has been written from the perspective of a Spain Spanish speaker. I don't know how the Spanish speakers from America might see it.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a correct translation for "fake news"? Yes, absolutely.

Is it a correct translation for "post-truth"? I don't think so. The *"appealing more to emotions and personal beliefs rather than facts"* connotation is missing in the Spanish word.

But that's not a problem, since "fake news" and "post-truth" aren't synonyms in English either.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, the RAE has just included *posverdad* in the DLE (update 23.1 from december 20, 2017):

> **[posverdad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TqpLe0m)**
>
> De *pos-* y *verdad*, trad. del ingl. *post-truth*.
>
> 1. f. Distorsión deliberada de una realidad, que manipula creencias y emociones con el fin de influir en la opinión pública y en actitudes sociales. *Los demagogos son maestros de la posverdad.*

So now you don't have to translate *post-truth* as *paparruchas*.